# I cannot log in to my account on Ubuntu desktop

Tags: 16.04, xorg, lightdm, login-screen

I see the log-in screen but when I select one and enter the password it fails to log me in. It easily enters into guest account by the way.

I suspected there is some graphical problem and checked Xorg log. There it couldn't access fb0 for permission problems.

I should note the problem started happening when I updated Ubuntu from 14 to 16.

I also looked at kernel log and noticed some problems there. So I started a new thread [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1110848/vmwgfx-error-in-kernel-log-on-ubuntu-16-04) which didn't get any response.

So I uninstalled and re-installed lightdm and Xorg and Ubuntu-desktop with no success.

Any idea on how to investigate the matter?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my user has lost ownership of some items in my home folder.

This was fixed with help of Eric^^ in #ubuntu.